# The getline() function

Tags: getline

I use the getline(cin,varname) function to enter a string with implemented blanks in it , but when I run the program it doesn't take any input from the user and moves on to the next line .

```
cout<<"Enter title : " ; getline(cin,title) ;
```

Comment: Please write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `std::getline`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string title;
  std::cout << "Please enter title: " << std::cout;
  std::getline(std::cin, title);

  std::cout << "\n" << title << " is a good title!\n";

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: what is the difference i use #include <iostream> , #include <string> , using namespace std

Comment: There is none.  `using namespace std` pulls in all of the cout/cin stuff along with the entirety of the iostream and string libraries.  It makes it easier to read, but it's not recommended because there are hundreds of names that you then can't use (what if you have your own "string" class, for example?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since you don't have an `endl`, the buffer hasn't flushed yet, so the input becomes the output that you printed.  Add an `endl` after the `getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string title;
  std::cout << "Please enter title: "<<std::endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, title);

  return 0;

}
```

If you REALLY want the input to be right beside the prompt, and you have to use `getline`, keeping in mind that you'll probably get the "Please enter title" prompt as well, then you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string title;
  std::cout << "Please enter title: "<<std::flush;
  std::getline(std::cin, title);

  return 0;

}
```